# How can I improve Firefox performance?

Tags: performance, firefox

I just "upgraded" to Firefox 57, the holy grail of alleged performance perks, yada yada. Im not here to complain that it breaks all the add ons. My problem is that the response time for IO is sickeningly slow now.

In FF56, I was able to click 56 times per second, which is handy in online gaming. With FireFox 57, I am only able to register mouse clicks at about 20 times per second. This is a devastating blow to performance.

Yes, I know how to uninstall, and get firefox 56 back. What I want to know is if there is some way I can boost the click recognition ability of Firefox 57, to that which it was, (or more).

Is there a way I can allow FF57 to utilize more RAM? Or some other method for getting the same performance or better, that was present in the previous version?

OS: Ubuntu Mate 17.04

Comment: 56 clicks per second? Wow, how do you avoid the overheating of your mouse? :-)

Comment: It gets warm, but doesn't over heat. For now, I will be using Firefox56. Until a solution presents itself, or I figure something out. A tip to get fast response time out of any browser: zooming out to 30% helps a lot. at 100% screen size, I get mad lag, before getting to the 60s range of Cps.

Comment: I am not sure that my answer will actually help, if it doesn't, I am ready to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a new development, so-named [electrolysis](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis). Its essence is that they gave up to build a multithreaded browser, and they switched to a mixed, multithreaded-multiprocess model.

The result is suboptimal memory consumption, zombie child processes and *decreased* speed.

Google chrome does the same, but they have much more programmers to make it better.

Fortunately, e10s can be turned off. Essentially, you have to search for "remote" in the about:config and switch every "true" boolean value to "false".

Comment: I'm confused. "suboptimal memory consumption, zombie child processes and decreased speed." This is supposed to be an improvement?

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, it is not an improvement, it is a conceptionally false direction, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh. Do you recommend I stay with 52 ESR on stable then?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I recommend to turn off the e10s. Furthermore, using 32-bit FF can also help a lot. Sad to say, but so is it. I was militant "do everything with 64-bit" long, but slowly the facts convinced me. The major reason, why the 32-bit ff still better is, the cpu cache.

Comment: I don't know what e10s. And why should I use 32 bit Firefox on a 64 bit system? Should we take this to chat? I'm in the main chat room - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat

Comment: Did you read my answer? [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) you may chat with others.

Comment: Hi peterh. Yes, of course I read your answer. I still don't understand you reference to 32 bit, though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It is because 32bit apps use much lesser RAM (roughly 50-60% or the 64-bit versions). It is because pointers are always 64bit in a 64bit process, and now as complex data structures are more and more common, the majority of the data segments are pointers. And, your CPU has also an internal cache, this is very fast, but very small (typically, some megabyte in recent CPUs - compare this to the 2-4GB memory footprint of a firefox). Thus, if you decrease the size of the data segment of the FF, you get much lesser cache misses, too.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The sad truth is that on Linux, simply there is no need to switch to 64-bit - except in the case of the few processes where *a single process* wants to use more that 3GB virtual memory. On Windows, the need is much more urgent - on 32-bit Windowses, *the summed memory usage of all processes* has this 3GB limit. The result is that on a 64-bit Linux system, enough if only the really large apps use 64bit (eclipse, firefox only if you like to open more than 50 tabs with 30 addons, and some similar). 64-bit kernel is still a need, because there are already many 64bit-only apps.